# How to add a ScrollBar to a Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel, scrollbars

In my WPF application, I have a Stackpanel containing several controls inside them. How can I add a Scrollbar to this stackpanel.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Put it into a [`ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. After putting a ScrollViewer around it, the entire content doesn't show up. I tried setting Height and Width to Auto, but no luck. Why should only a limited portion show?

Comment: I have no clue. Your question was two sentences long which is a bit little detail to anticipate any potential problems.

Comment: Got it, I was placing the opening tag in the wrong place. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Simple and perfect answer.

Answer (score 128):

Stackpanel doesn't have built in scrolling mechanism but you can always wrap the StackPanel in a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <StackPanel ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Well, `StackPanel` does implement `IScrollInfo` and offers a number of scrolling-related methods. Are you sure it does not have any kind of "built-in" scrolling mechanism?

Comment: from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.canverticallyscroll(v=vs.110).aspx... "This property is not intended for use in your code. It is exposed publicly to fulfill an interface contract (IScrollInfo). Setting this property has no effect.

If you require physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling, wrap the StackPanel in a ScrollViewer and set its CanContentScroll property to false."

Answer (score 15):

It works like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" Width="311">

        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

---

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(TextBox_TextChanged);
stackPanel1.Children.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 3):

For horizontally oriented StackPanel, explicitly putting both the scrollbar visibilities worked for me to get the horizontal scrollbar.

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Repeat of previous answers.

Answer (score -4):

If you mean, you want to scroll through multiple items in your stackpanel, try putting a grid around it. By definition, a stackpanel has infinite length.

So try something like this:

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Width="311">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontStretch="Condensed" FontSize="28" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

You could even make this work with a ScrollViewer

Comment: This code is taken out of context. Could you remove the dependencies, so the code is usable without further modifications?