# How to scroll the datagrid in stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, stackpanel

I want to scroll the `datagrid` when it's length exceeds the `stackpanel`, so I tried this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                         
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
       <DataGrid Name="dgConfig" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
             <DataGrid.Columns>
              ...
             </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
   </ScrollViewer>                                
</StackPanel>
```

But this doesn't work, I have searched on this web and failed to find any avaiable solutions. So how should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: use other panels such as grid or dockpanel?

Comment: [How to add a ScrollBar to a Stackpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250240/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-a-stackpanel)

Comment: How does your code example behaves? Is StackPanel height increased instead of showing scrollbar?

Comment: The scrollbar didn't show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ScrollViewers` and `StackPanels` don't work very well together since a `StackPanel` measures its child elements with infinite horizontal space if its `Orientation` property is set to `Horizontal` and infinite vertical space if it is set to `Vertical`.

So you will either have to specify a height for the `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
```

If you don't it will have an infinite height and that's why you see no scrollbars.

The other, and much better option, would be to get rid of the `StackPanel` and use another `Panel` that doesn't measures its child elements with an infinite space.

The `DataGrid` has its own `ScrollViewer` built-in, so you don't need to put it inside a `ScrollViewer` element yourself. Get rid of the `StackPanel`(s) and the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgConfig" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

DockPanel instead of StackPanel works for me.

Answer (score -1):

try adding VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto", ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" to datagrid property.