# XAML/WPF - ScrollViewer which has StackPanel inside is not scrolling

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer that shows User Control elements Whenever a specific event occurs:

***Note: many UserControls might appear in the StackPanel that's why I added a Scrollviewer***

```
<ScrollViewer 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Grid.Row="2"
        CanContentScroll="True" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserControls}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:UserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Although, the StackPanel is still going out of range and the scroll bars doesn't show and doesn't work!

I tried fixing the height of both the StackPanel and the ItemsControl but it does't seem to work either...

**Window Layout containing the ScrollViewer:**

```
<Grid Margin="0,15,0,0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label 
        Content="This is a Label" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="5,5,0,0"
        FontSize="15"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    </Label>


    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Something}"
            Text="Confirm with..."
            SelectedItem="{Binding Something}"/>
        <Button
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="5"
            Content="Add new UserControl"
            Command="{Binding Path=AddUserControl}"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Grid.Row="2"
        CanContentScroll="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserControls}" Height="300">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:UserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

**Here's my UserControl that is added to the StackPanel Inside the ScrollViewer:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        Grid.Row="0">

        <Button
            Name="DeleteFilter" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="5"
            Content="-"/>

        <ComboBox 
            Margin="5"
            IsEditable="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Width="150"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObject}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SomeObjectProperty}"/>

        <ComboBox 
            Margin="5"
            IsEditable="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Width="150"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherObject}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedItem="{Binding AnotherObjectProperty}"/>

        <TextBox 
            x:Name="Value"
            Text="{Binding TextBoxValueString}"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            Width="100"
            Margin="5"
            Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisibility}"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

*I'm new to XAML and WPF.*

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please show the whole layout code in reference of what parents the scroll viewer has and what properties are set on them?

Comment: Your code is working fine on my machine, are you by chance overriding the style of the Scroll Viewer somewhere in your application?

Comment: Well that's weird. No, Not really. I'm not overriding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollViewers` and `StackPanel` don't work well together. This is because a `StackPanel` measures its child elements with infinite horizontal space if its `Orientation` property is set to `Horizontal` and infinite vertical space if it is set to `Vertical`. Please refer to my answer here for more information:

[How to scroll the datagrid in stackpanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135242/how-to-scroll-the-datagrid-in-stackpanel/45144557#45144557)

So you should replace the `StackPanel` with another `Panel` or remove it altogether:

```
<ScrollViewer 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Grid.Row="2"
        CanContentScroll="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserControls}" Height="300">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:UserControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Dear @mm8, this is the second time you answer my stackoverflow questions and you nailed it, twice :) ... Thank's a lot. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it run with this setting:

```
   <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 Grid.RowSpan="10">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.RowSpan="6"
                Name="SPanel"
                Margin="0,0,-0.4,1.4"
                CanVerticallyScroll="True">
      <Border BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Margin="3"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Name="ChartHolder0">
        <dvc:Chart Cursor="Cross"
                   Background="#FFFFFCF2" />
      </Border>
      <Border BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Margin="3"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Name="ChartHolder0">
        <dvc:Chart Cursor="Cross"
                   Background="#FFFFFCF2" />
      </Border>
      <Border BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Margin="3"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Name="ChartHolder0">
        <dvc:Chart Cursor="Cross"
                   Background="#FFFFFCF2">
        </dvc:Chart>
      </Border>
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: StackPanel and ScrollViewer]

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a fix for this problem and Mishka's answer worked for me.

I don't have enough reputation to comment on an answer, but wanted to say that Background="White" fix from Mishka does work for me on Silverlight (didn't try WPF).

```
<ScrollViewer Background="White">
  <StackPanel Margin="5" Background="White">
```

Works, if I only put Background on the StackPanel the 5 pixel Margin on the stackpanel doesn't scroll. If I don't put Background on either then both the 5 pixel margin and any margins on controls inside the stackpanel dont scroll.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a Background for either the StackPanel or ItemsControl(Your choise).
Default Background is Null.
With Background Null, the ScrollViewer doesn't get mouse events for the mouse wheel,
and doesn't scroll.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
Background="LightGray"... If you do, then No, it didn't work. The panel still goes out of the window's range

Comment: The background has nothing to do with the visibility of a scroll viewer