# C# WPF - Make DataGrid stretch to available size, not expand the available size

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, width

I use Visual Studio 2010.  I've been struggling trying to get a datagrid to fill the existing space.  If necessary, to show a scrollbar on the datagrid, not on the page.

Example code:

```
<Page x:Class="TestApp.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="Page1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander x:Name="MyExpander"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Header="My Expander"
              Expanded="MyExpander_Expanded"
              Collapsed="MyExpander_Collapsed">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid Margin="5"
                      Height="100"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFirstColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySecondColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyThirdColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFourthColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFifthColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySixthColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySeventhColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyEighthColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyNinthColumn"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyTenthColumn"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="DoSomething"
                Margin="5"
                Width="100"
                Height="30"
                Content="Do Something"
                Click="DoSomething_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

The problem is, it seems, whatever I do, the datagrid will always stretch until all columns are completely visible, even if it stretches way past the window (or page) size.
Note: I have a panel on the right, showing status, dates, info, ..., which should stay on the screen.

I have tried too many things to list them all.  The only working 'solution' I found is adding another control (invisible) like a separator on the grid and binding the expander width to the width of the separator.  It works, but it's crappy programming.

```
MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=MySeparator, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Binding the width of the stackpanel to the (actual) width of the column just make the stackpanel disappear.

Can someone please help me.  Thank you.

-- Update --
This is what I like to achieve:
[image]

It seems that if I use hardcoded column widths, this problem doesn't occur.  Only if there is a column that has a star-length, the datagrid takes as much space as it needs.

Comment: To be clear, you want your data grid to size itself according to its contents, and the viewbox to scale the grid up or down (i.e., magnify/demagnify) to fit the space actually available?  Actually, could you just provide a mockup of what you _want_ the result to look like?

Comment: Not really, I want the datagrid to fit the column size, if I resize the window, it should become bigger/smaller.  The datagrid can have a scrollbar if there are too many columns.  I just don't want the datagrid to stretch the column, what is currently happening.  If I wanted the column to stretch to the size of the datagrid, I would have used column width = auto.

Comment: Could you sketch out a quick mockup of what the results should look like under the various conditions you describe?  Maybe make a quick pen and paper sketch, then take a photo of it with your phone?

Comment: I have created an image what exactly it is I want to do: [Pic (tinypic)](http://tinypic.com/r/2ylmxvm/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the efforts.  The solution was proposed by [Mike Strobel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175070/mike-strobel) in a comment.  Since I can't mark comments as, I'll repeat it here.

I had a window, containing a scrollviewer, where all page are placed on.  I removed the scrollviewer from the window and placed the scrollbars on the page.

```
<Page x:Class=...>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
```

This actually solves the problem!  Thanks Mike!

(If you run into this problem as well, please give mike's comment a thumbs up as well).

Answer (score 1):

Since your diagram only addressed the scrolling issue, I have focused on that for now.  It's still not entirely clear to me how you want this layout to look *before* scrolling is required, but let's use this as a starting point.  Give it a try, and if the behavior isn't what you had in mind, please try to be as specific as possible about what needs to change (a picture is worth a thousand words).

For brevity, I'm only including the `Expander` and its content.  The ancestor elements are exactly as they were in your original post.

```
<Expander x:Name="MyExpander"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="1"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Header="My Expander"
          Expanded="MyExpander_Expanded"
          Collapsed="MyExpander_Collapsed">
  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Margin="5"
              xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
      <!-- Temporary items source to demonstrate grid measuring to fit rows -->
      <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="s:String">
          <s:String>Dummy Row 1</s:String>
          <s:String>Dummy Row 2</s:String>
          <s:String>Dummy Row 3</s:String>
        </x:Array>
      </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFirstColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySecondColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyThirdColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFourthColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFifthColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySixthColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySeventhColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyEighthColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyNinthColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyTenthColumn" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="DoSomething"
            Margin="5"
            Width="100"
            Height="30"
            Content="Do Something"
            Click="DoSomething_Click" />
  </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

This is how it looks with two columns:

[[image: Grid with 2 Columns[2]]

This is how it looks with ten columns:

[image: Grid with 10 Columns]

### Update

According to your comments on another answer, your page is loaded inside a `ScrollViewer` at runtime.  If that `ScrollViewer` supports horizontal scrolling, then that is the root of you problems: it will give your page as much horizontal space as it needs, and that need is being driven by the `DataGrid`.  One (hacky) workaround would be to wrap your `DataGrid` in a custom decorator that fakes its desired width when measured and then fills whatever horizontal space is available when arranged.  If you want to try this out, use my example from above, but wrap the `DataGrid` in a decorator like so:

```
<l:ZeroWidthDecorator xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestApp">
  <DataGrid><!-- ... --></DataGrid>
</l:ZeroWidthDecorator>
```

The code for the decorator is as follows:

```
public class ZeroWidthDecorator : Border
{
    private Size _lastSize;
    private Size _idealSize;

    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject added, DependencyObject removed)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(added, removed);
        _idealSize = new Size();
        _lastSize = new Size();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var child = this.Child;
        if (child == null)
            return new Size();
        if (child.IsMeasureValid)
            child.Measure(new Size(_lastSize.Width, Math.Max(_lastSize.Height, constraint.Height)));
        else
            child.Measure(new Size(0d, constraint.Height));
        _idealSize = child.DesiredSize;
        return new Size(0d, _idealSize.Height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var child = this.Child;
        if (child != null)
        {
            if (arrangeSize != _lastSize)
            {
                // Our parent will assume our measure is the same if the last
                // arrange bounds are still available, so force a reevaluation.
                this.InvalidateMeasure();
            }
            child.Arrange(new Rect(arrangeSize));
        }
        _lastSize = arrangeSize;
        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this extensively, but I tried a few different scenarios, and it *seems* to work.  **Use it at your own risk.**

Comment: Thank you!  I think this should work. It looks perfect in visual studio, yet at runtime I keep getting the same result.  I placed the datagrid on the grid, without any panels, expanders, ...  It will always expand the page it seems.  Did I run into a VS2010 bug?  It starts to feel more and more that way.

Comment: In another comment, you mentioned that the `Page` is being displayed inside a `ScrollViewer`.  If I had to guess, I'd say that's your problem.

Comment: @JanSolo I added an update to my answer that provides a (rather hacky) way to prevent the grid from single-handedly growing the page wider than the viewport on the window's `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `DataGrid` with `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid>
        // SOME CONTENT
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Also I don't know if you need that `ViewBox` at all. Try removing it and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: The `DataGrid` should really handle its own scrolling.  I agree that a `Viewbox` sounds like the wrong approach, but this shouldn't be necessary either.

Comment: Yes, it should, but for some reason it doesn't act like it does by default when it's nested in the `Expander`. I agree it's not a perfect solution, since it is scrolling the `DataGrid` along with its headers, but I haven't found better one yet.

Comment: The page is placed on a window which has a scrollviewer.  Scrolling is handeled by the window, not the page.  I've tried this and I get the same results as before.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `StackPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander x:Name="MyExpander"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Header="My Expander"
              Expanded="MyExpander_Expanded"
              Collapsed="MyExpander_Collapsed">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <DataGrid Margin="5"
                      Height="100"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFirstColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySecondColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyThirdColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFourthColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyFifthColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySixthColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MySeventhColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyEighthColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyNinthColumn"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyTenthColumn"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button x:Name="DoSomething"
                Margin="5"
                Width="100"
                Height="30"
                Content="Do Something"
                Click="DoSomething_Click"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

`StackPanels` and `ScrollViewers` don't work well together because of the way a `StackPanel` measures its children:

[XAML/WPF - ScrollViewer which has StackPanel inside is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802078/xaml-wpf-scrollviewer-which-has-stackpanel-inside-is-not-scrolling/45820825#45820825)

And since the default control template of the `DataGrid` includes a `ScrollViewer` you don't need to add your own one.