# Need explanation for data loading behavior of a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf window defined in XAML as follows:

```
<Window
    [The usual stuff]>
    <Window.Resources>
        [Some resources]
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray>
            [Two toolbars]
        </ToolBarTray>
        <DataGrid>
            [Stuff]
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
<Window>
```

The `DataGrid` has an `ObservableCollection` as the `ItemsSource`.

In this configuration, the `DataGrid` is populated as the user scrolls down through the data rows.

If I change the `DockPanel` to a `StackPanel` - **and change nothing else** - all rows of data are loaded when the window is Loaded.

Why the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the difference in behavior?

The `StackPanel` disables the UI virtualization of the `DataGrid` because it measures its child elements with infinite vertical space:

[Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work/41140885#41140885)

[XAML/WPF - ScrollViewer which has StackPanel inside is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802078/xaml-wpf-scrollviewer-which-has-stackpanel-inside-is-not-scrolling/45820825#45820825)

Comment: Spot on, as usual.  But I have read the page about the StackPanel and it says nothing (that I saw, at least) about the infinite space, depending on orientation.  Where did you get that information?

Comment: @SezMe: Check out the panels overview on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview. "This is because StackPanel measures in the direction of stacking at PositiveInfinity...".